# how to insert hexadecimal byte in a particular position in a given string

Tags: java, android

I want to insert hexadecimal byte for example 0A and 00 in a particular position in a given string i.e.,String set="16 10 36 07 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0B 11 B7 93"; i want to insert 0A and 00 in 4th and 5th position of the given string. How can i write a code in java

Answer (score 1):

I've got a quick snippet for you, works fine!

```
public static String insertAtPos(String input, int pos, String insert) {
    return
    String.format("%s%s%s%s",input.substring(0, 3 * pos), insert, " ", input.substring(3 * pos, input.length()));
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String set= "16 10 36 07 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0B 11 B7 93";
    String s0A = "0A";
    String sFF = "FF";

    System.out.println(insertAtPos(set, 4, s0A));
    System.out.println(insertAtPos(set, 5, sFF));       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
String set2 = set.substring(0, 9) + "0A 00 " + set.substring(9);
```

That will give you `16 10 36 0A 00 07 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0B 11 B7 93`

If you want something more general, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't alter the contents of a string itself, but you can change the `set` variable to refer to a different string. (Or use a different variable if you want.)

The fact that you want to use hex here it irrelevant really. The "4th and 5th position" just means "after index 9 in the string" given that the index is just characters (each "hex byte" of your string is represented by two hex digits and a space; three characters). So:

```
set = set.substring(0, 9) + "0A 00 " + set.substring(9);
```